# Why can't I generalize this from Monad to Applicative?

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

I generalized [`hoistFree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.1/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html#v%3ahoistFree) from the [*free*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) package to `hoistFreeM`, similarly to how one can generalize `fmap` to `Data.Traversable.mapM`.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Free
import Data.Traversable as T

hoistFreeM :: (Traversable g, Monad m) =>
              (forall a. f a -> m (g a)) -> Free f b -> m (Free g b)
hoistFreeM f = go
  where go (Pure x)  = return $ Pure x
        go (Free xs) = liftM Free $ T.mapM go =<< f xs
```

However, I don't think there is a way to further generalize it to work with any `Applicative`, similarly to how one can generalize `Data.Traversable.mapM` to `Data.Traversable.traverse`. Am I correct? If so, why?

Comment: Do you mean generalize `Monad m` to `Applicative m`, or `Traversable g` to `Applicative g`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't lift an Applicative through a Free Monad because the Monad structure demands choice (via `(>>=)` or `join`) and the Applicative can't provide that. But, perhaps unsurprisingly, you can lift an Applicative through a Free Applicative

```
-- also from the `free` package
data Ap f a where
  Pure :: a -> Ap f a
  Ap :: f a -> Ap f (a -> b) -> Ap f b

hoistAp :: (forall a. f a -> g a) -> Ap f b -> Ap g b
hoistAp _ (Pure a) = Pure a
hoistAp f (Ap x y) = Ap (f x) (hoistAp f y)

hoistApA :: Applicative v => (forall a. f a -> v (g a)) -> Ap f b -> v (Ap g b)
hoistApA _ (Pure a) = pure (Pure a)
hoistApA f (Ap x y) = Ap <$> f x <*> hoistApA f y

-- just what you'd expect, really
```

---

To be more explicit, let's try generalizing `hoistFreeM` to `hoistFreeA`. It's easy enough to begin

```
hoistFreeA :: (Traversable f, Applicative v) =>
              (forall a. f a -> v (g a)) -> Free f b -> v (Free g b)
hoistFreeA _ (Pure a) = pure (Pure a)
```

And we can try to continue by analogy from `hoistFreeM` here. `mapM` becomes `traverse` and we can get as far as

```
hoistFreeA f (Free xs) = ?f $ traverse (hoistFreeA f) xs
```

where I've been using `?f` as a makeshift type hole to try to figure out how to move forward. We can complete this definition if we can make

```
?f :: v (f (Free g b)) -> v (Free g b)
```

In other words, we need to transform that `f` layer into a `g` layer while living underneath our `v` layer. It's easy enough to get underneath `v` since `v` is a `Functor`, but the only way we have to transform `f a` to `g a` is our argument function `forall a . f a -> v (g a)`.

We can try applying that `f` anyway along with a `Free` wrapper in order to fold up our `g` layer.

```
hoistFreeA f (Free xs) = ?f . fmap (fmap Free . f) $ traverse (hoistFreeA f) xs
```

But now we have to solve

```
?f :: v (v (Free g b)) -> v (Free g b)
```

which is just `join`, so we're stuck. This is fundamentally where we're always going to get stuck. Free Monads model Monads and thus in order to wrap over them we need to somehow `join` or `bind`.

Comment: I understand what immediately blocks me from writing the function. I'm more interested in some theory about *why* this happens. You say "Free Monads model Monads and thus in order to wrap over them we need to somehow `join` or `bind`," which basically lines up with my own intuitive guess, but this doesn't help me understand why, for example, I can write `traverseFree :: (Applicative f, Traversable g) => (a -> f b) -> Free g a -> f (Free g b)`, but not `hoistFreeA :: (Traversable g, Applicative h) => (forall a. f a -> h (g a)) -> Free f b -> h (Free g b)`.

Comment: You need the `Traversable` constraint on the underlying `Functor` of your input `Free` monad. If you notice, that's where it's at for `traverseFree` as well.

Comment: The best I can do to talk about it theoretically is just to compare the different `Free` tree shapes. Since the Free monads and applicatives are both initial, we know that we can use them as models to talk generally about mappings between those two categories. `Free` monads build their trees via Functor composition while free `Ap`plicatives do it via products. If all you have is a natural transformation from your source functor to your target functor wrapped in an applicative, then you can't apply that "downward" through a composition of functors without `join`, but you can traverse `(,)`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean from your comment about the `Traversable` constraint. The `Traversable` constraint is on the underlying `Functor` of the *output* `Free` monad in both functions. Maybe that's what you meant.

Comment: Ah, I see now. The functor composition is the cause.